# Is there always a line that intersects a given Zariski-closed set in finite number of points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume that we're working in an algebraically closed field. Let $X \subsetneq \mathbb{A}^n$ be a Zariski-closed set. Is there a line in $\mathbb{A}^n$ that intersects $X$ in finitely many points? I need a hint.

Comment: Is $X$ supposed to be properly contained in $\mathbb{A}^n$? And should "algebraically closed set" be "algebraically closed field"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan it was a typo :) About $X$, assume you're talking to someone who doesn't know the first thing about schemes.

Comment: @Alexei: I think Qiaochu's point is that if $X=\mathbb{A}^n$ the answer is trivially no (since any algebraically closed field is infinite).

Comment: @ZevChonoles Oh :) Yeah, I meant a proper subset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that a line $\ell$ intersects $X$ in infinitely many points.  The intersection is an infinite Zariski closed subset of $X$ and $\ell$.  Now $X$ may have lots of different infinite Zariski closed subsets (depending on what it is), but what about $\ell$?

Comment: Once again, AG is so easy once someone explained it :D Thanks!